# the following code of displaying lower triangular matrix in c is running infinitely in dev c++ compiler? can anyone please check and correct me?

Tags: c, matrix, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct matrix 
{
    int *A;
    int n;
};


void set(struct matrix *m , int i , int j , int x)
{
    if(i>=j)
        m->A[i*(i-1)/2+(j-1)]=x;
}

void display(struct matrix m)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=m.n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;i<=m.n;j++)
        {
            if(i>=j)
                print f("%d ",m.A[i*(i-1)/2+j-1]);
            else
                print f("0 ");
        }
        print f("\n");
    }
}

int get(struct matrix m , int i , int j)
{
    if(i>=j)
        return m.A[i*(i-1)/2+(j-1)];
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,x;
    struct matrix m;

    print f("Enter Dimension of matrix : \n");
    scan f("%d",&m.n);
    m.A=(int *)malloc((m.n*(m.n-1)/2)*sizeof(int));
    
    print f("Enter Elements : \n");
    for(i=1;i<=m.n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m.n;j++)
        {
            scan f("%d",&x);
            set(&m,i,j,x);
        }
    }
    print f("\n\n");
    display(m);
    print f("\n\n");
    print f("Value at particular index : %d",get(m,3,2));
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Typo: `for(j=1;i<=m.n;j++)` Note the `i` there.

Comment: Why have you written `print f` and `scan f`??  The functions are `printf` and `scanf`.

Comment: thank you for your correction . code is working fine now

Comment: Not relevant to the nontermination, but I would worry about whether i*(i-1)/2 will always be computed as (i*(i-1))/2 -- which is what is needed -- or might be computed as i*((i-1)/2) which will be wrong for even i

Answer (score 2):

in your function display
your loop is  `for(i=1;i<=m.n;i++) { for(j=1;i<=m.n;j++) }`
your inner for should be `for(j=1;j<=m;j++)` ur inner loop waiting for condition i<=m and will never come true ..

Comment: Thank you Mr. omar for your correction. Now Code is Working perfectly